# Reduce Amazon Cloud Search Upload and Searchable Document timing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudsearch

I am upload document to Amazon Cloud Search . Document have 29 fields 13 text fields and other int. But only text fields are searchable.

**Like**

**vendorName - text, VendorClass - text etc.**

Now I am uploading document with key "AAA" and printing document upload timing .

vendorName ="AAA"

Like

**Start time - 05:54:23.95 , End time - 05:54:23.100**

And on other thread I am searching same key "AAA" and counting how many document available on Amazon cloud on which timing. Its in loop and running before inserting document.

Like

**Found 101 document with "AAA" key on 05:54:26:445**

When I am uploading 1 document its taking more then 3 seconds to available for search and when uploading 1000 (Bulk) documents its taking around 5-8 seconds to available to search.

I want reduce document searchable time for 1 record. How it possible ?

Have anybody measured single document searchable timing ?

It is possible document available less then 1 seconds on amazon cloud . Means upload time - 05:54:24.00 and available time - 05:54:24.95?

Comment: Return fields used to be expensive in terms of performance -- so much so that there was a limit of 10 until the V2 API. I'm not sure whether there's still a cost attached to them, but you could try disabling the various indexing options (Search, Sort, Facet, Return, Highlight) on fields where you know you won't need them. Other than that, all I can think to try is throwing more hardware at it -- try a `search.m3.2xlarge` and see if that speeds things up.

Comment: I disabled all search on all field on enabled on "text" field which default . and instance is "search.m3.2xlarge" without partition , Its also not reducing time.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back with the results. Is your CloudSearch domain in the same region that the requests are coming from? That's the only other thing I can think to check because CloudSearch is a black box without a lot of knobs to turn.

Comment: Yes, Both Cloud search and Search key application(Design By Us) hosted on US West . same region.